# Read String and convert it to array with ; as new item

Tags: arrays, string, windows, powershell

I have a some strings that looks like this:

```
$str = '192.168.10.1;192.168.10.30;10.215.30.30;'
```

i would to read this type of strings and take each string and create an array of it where the ';' sign signlas end of an item
so i should have an array:

```
$arr[0] = 192.168.10.1 
$arr[1] = 192.168.10.30
.
.
.
```

can someone assist please?

Comment: Use the `-split` operator.

Comment: Thank you i was unaware of that operator